# Not able to get data in one-to-many mapping

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

I am trying to get batchInfoEntityList from BatchEntity entity like this:

```
@Entity(name = "batch")
public class BatchEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long batchId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH,
        CascadeType.REMOVE }, mappedBy="batchEntity")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<BatchInfoEntity> batchInfoEntityList;

}
```

And my BatchInfoEntity is :

```
@Entity(name = "batch_info")
public class BatchInfoEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long batchInfoId;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch =         FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = BatchEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "batchId", referencedColumnName = "batchId")
    private BatchEntity batchEntity; 
}
```

But when I get batchEntity instance, its batchInfoEntityList is empty. I am not able to understand why it is happening.

My DAO is

```
public List<BatchEntity> getA()
        throws Exception {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<BatchEntity> batchEntityList = session
                .createQuery(
                        "select b from "
                                + BatchEntity.class.getName()
                                + " b ")


        return batchEntityList;
    }  finally {
        session.close();
        // session.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you might have to use HQL or the Criteria to take advantage of the fetching strategy. Since you are relying on query, you might have to do a join.

Comment: I am using query only but doesn't it suppose to get the list automatically...? I am getting data in other scenario using the same approach.

Comment: You may want to check this topic here, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html if you want to fetch the join table, you have to specify join condition there. I have not seen anything here which says that hibernate automatically pulls the data based on the association.